# Wlan0 interface disappeared after upgrade to Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, broadcom, thinkpad, 16.04

Since the upgrade from to Xubuntu 16.04 from Xubuntu 15.10 on a *Lenovo Thinkpad Twist (S230u)* with *Broadcom wireless card* **the wlan0 device has disappeared**. It is as though the physical device was inexistent.
**How can it be re-activated ?**

During the last step of the upgrade process I clicked *NO* regarding the question whether I wanted to deactivate *UEFI Secure Boot*. (I don't know whether this is a useful information).

The system is currently up to date.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

--> finish with *0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.*

```
ifconfig
```

--> only lists *eth0* and *lo*.

```
lspci
```

--> contains a line
    "*03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n*". But there is no mention of "wireless" or the like.

```
iwconfig
```

--> mentions *eth0*, *wwan0*, *lo*, each with *no wireless extensions*. Nothing else.

```
 nmcli -f all device show
```

--> Same situation. *GENERAL.DEVICE* entries only for *eth0*, *lo* and *cdc-wdm3* (which should be the mobile broadband device).

```
update-manager
```

--> mentions under *Additional drivers* : Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n - *Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary).*

**I tried the solution suggested by David Foerster. But the re-installation process finishes with an error. The situation remains as it is:**

```
lspci -nn -d 14e4:
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get update-pciids
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

The result is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bcmwl-kernel-source
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1 515 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8 013 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package bcmwl-kernel-source.
(Reading database ... 259730 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-     0ubuntu8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.248+bdcom DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 4.4.0-21-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.4.0-21-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-21-generic
```

**Disabling validation via mokutil as described below didn't help either.**

Comment: @Woozle  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Ubuntu 16.04 does not install unsigned third party packages if Secure Boot is enabled.

You need to disable Secure Boot in UEFI settings to get `wl` work.

But that is a problem, because on some systems Secure Boot can't be disabled.

**Update:** This issue can be fixed. You can disable validation of modules by:

```
sudo apt-get install mokutil
sudo mokutil --disable-validation
```

Comment: I have a similar issue to OP's, except I have Realtek, not Broadcom, and my laptop is older than Secure Boot and UEFI. This is a real pain.

Comment: I disabled validation via mokutil, then rebooted. After purging bcmwl-kernel-source, I re-installed it. The result is still the same : "modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available".

Comment: Maybe it is something wrong with you UEFI. Try to disable it there.

Comment: Yes, thanks. After disabling SecureBoot in the BIOS the wlan interface was immediately available again.